# Tcp listener vs Http Listener

Tags: c#

My needs are to send just a simple string. Which method is more right to use, or faster with better performance.

HttpListener

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

    foreach (string s in prefixes)
    {
        listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
    }
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Listening..");

    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
    HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

    string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Test </BODY></HTML>";
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
    Stream output = response.OutputStream;
    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    output.Close();
    listener.Stop();
```

TcpListener

```
    IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("172.21.5.99");
        TcpListener myList=new TcpListener(ipAd,8001);
        myList.Start();
        Socket s=myList.AcceptSocket();
        byte[] b=new byte[100];
        int k=s.Receive(b);
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
        for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
            Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

        ASCIIEncoding asen=new ASCIIEncoding();
        s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));

        s.Close();
        myList.Stop();
```

I need to send from my client a string with some values, example Name=xxx,Age=xxx
,then server to take this string and answering with an "OK"

Comment: HttpListener obviously is listening to *HTTP* requests and needs to resolve them (headers etc.), TcpListener is operating on raw Tcp connections. TcpListener would thus be faster.

Comment: HTTP is a protocol on top of TCP. So 'bare' TCP is simpler, and should be enough if you just want to send "Hey, you there?" - "Yes"

Comment: Thank you, that what i was looking for. What about other methods? Web service, asp net. Till now i dont care for something more than a single string. Are the other methods faster or better?

Comment: Look up OSI, HTTP, and TCP, explaining this here in a comment/answer is pretty much off-topic. What do you need? Is the overhead from 'higer level' protocols worth the features it brings? (e.g. HTTP status codes, w/e)